# Does the Pencil Project have a reusable components feature?

Tags: desktop-application

The [Pencil Project](https://pencil.evolus.vn/) is a tool made for proto-typing and for that I would need a feature of reusable components. For instance, when creating a header component I want to re-use it several times in the same document and have the changes I make to that component propagate to everywhere it is used.

The workaround I use now is to update the header in place and the copy those changes to all the other places where the header is being used which is a slow and error-prone process.

I did not find such feature in Pencil. Does it have such a feature?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about how to use a tool.

Answer (score 1):

Just looking at the page (I don't use Pencil myself) a possible workaround could be making a 'stencil'.

A listed feature is importing stencils from web/commumity. If these are dynamically loaded into the file at app-launch or when opening a design, you can theorerically follow these steps:
-design a header
-save as stencil
-use stencil to make headers in all interface designs
Then if you want to update the file:
-make a new design
-save as stencil and overwrite the name&file of the other stencil
-re-open the app and different interface designs.

Or perhaps a similar solution if it uses external file linking (either jpg or svg or whatever).

This is still quite convoluted though, so depending on the amount of interface varieties and header instances it might be easier to just copy and paste.

Sidenote: i'm not quite sure if this is the right board for this question, since it's more about tools and implementation than design practices.

Comment: I will have to try that out. Thank you for the suggestion. 
About the board: I have to admit that I posted my question here because I felt a question about a proto-typing tool is related to UX like Photoshop questions are related to Graphics design.